# Can bombs gain weapon runes?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, alchemy

[Bombs](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=703) are classified as martial thrown weapons. Neither the [fundamental](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=738) nor [property](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?Category=23&Subcategory=27) runes state that the weapon cannot be consumable.

Is there anything stopping me from getting [Thrower's Bandolier](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=2313), loading it out with 20 bombs each day and having them gain benefits of all the runes applied to the bandolier whenever drawn?

Would +3 major striking Thrower's Bandolier essentially turn lesser Alchemist Fire into a major one, with the exception of splash and persistent damage?

Comment: For some reason when I saw the title of this post I imaged a rune-etched GBU-32 1000lb bomb being dropped from an F/A-18 and thinking "we are so screwed".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## No

> [Runes must be etched onto **permanent items**, such as armor, weapons, or runestones to grant their benefit.](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=700)

Bombs, while weapons, are not permanent items. They are consumables. See Table 6–4: Treasure by level in Advanced Player's Guide. Bombs are listed under "Consumables" and not under "Permanent Items" which appear in the same table.